# Is it enough to just vote an answer up?

Tags: discussion, votes

I just found a really useful answer to a question (that wasn't mine), and have voted it up. Is it ok to add a comment thanking the person that wrote the answer? Or is the fact I voted it up enough?

Comment: If you just want to say "thanks" then that is what the upvote button does - an upvote is a thank you. If you want to say *"Thanks, your reply for Windows 2008 also works in Windows 2008r2, but you also have to...."* then that is also helping others so worth adding.

Comment: A quick look over the site will reveal that the very vast majority of votes, either up or down, are not accompanied by a comment.

Answer (score 13):

*"Or is the fact I voted it up enough?"*

In a word: [Yes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/).

Comment: +1, Please refrain from using Salutations, Signatures, Thank You, etc.

Comment: +1 This was also discussed recently in the IT Security beta's Meta:  http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/4/953

Answer (score 3):

If you found it particularly helpful *and can explain why in a way that illuminates* then feel free to leave a comment as well.

Comment: +1 Don't waste screen space and clog the db just to give a one-word "Thanks".